# Problem defining a new command using lstinputlisting

Tags: macros, listings

I am trying to define a new command to easily insert SQL queries (from a file) on my document.

I define it like that

```
\newcommand{\sqlfile}[2]{\lstinputlisting[language=SQL, caption={#1}, label=#2]{../sources/#2.sql}}
```

And use it like that

```
\sqlfile{Total number of users}{nb_users}
```

It works fine. I am able to reference the SQL file `\ref{...}` and the query is inserted correctly.

Now I want to insert the filename in the query caption, so I just added the `#2` in the `caption` parameter.

```
\newcommand{\sqlfile}[2]{\lstinputlisting[language=SQL, caption={#1 #2}, label=#2]{../sources/#2.sql}}
```

But it does not work, and I cannot figure out why.

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text>
$
l.1072 \sqlfile{Total number of users}{nb_users}
I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think you left one out. 
Proceed, with fingers crossed.
```

I tried adding braces and other, but that was not successful.
Thanks

Comment: I think it's the underscore that's giving you problems. What happens if you rename `nb_users` to `nbusers`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `_` is legal in file names, it's not in normal text. A trick that can save you might be

```
\newcommand{\sqlfile}[2]{%
  \lstinputlisting
    [language=SQL,
     caption={#1 \protect\detokenize{#2}},
     label=#2]
    {../sources/#2.sql}}
```

You must also call

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

for this to work.

The `\detokenize` command will change the nature of the `_` character in such a way that it's acceptable in normal text. With `\protect` we ensure that the `\detokenize` command is written also in the `.lol` (List of Listings) file.

Comment: You're right, this is because of the `_`. For some reason, your solution does not work. I will try to find a less hacky solution. Thanks

Comment: @Jonas In my test it worked. What's the new problem?

Comment: I get a huge error that I don't understand. https://gist.github.com/2032621 (and it takes ages to compile now)

Comment: @Jonas See edited message. Just adding `\protect` does the trick.